# How to Check Ethernet state using Command Prompt on Windows 10?

Tags: batch-file, networking, cmd, windows-10, windows

Windows usually shows a yellow sign over Network icon(Notification icons in Taskbar) in case when Ethernet is connected but not configured or no Internet.

Can I check if the same using Command Prompt?
I wanted to use such condition in a Batch File.

Comment: Will this give you what you want? `powershell -NoProfile -Command get-NetIPConfiguration`

Comment: I wanted to put a batch file in my startup folder that would dial up a Connection in case there's no Internet. That command did give me details about my interface but I'm not sure if I'd be able to use it automated.

Comment: I am not sure that networking will be fully configured when the startup programs run. I think you can get this down to a single .bat file, but when to run it might be a question.

Comment: @PrashantVishwakarma The command from lit is designed to work in a command prompt and batch files.

Comment: @SteveFest Yeah I did get a tabular output and it had most of the stuff I wanted.  `powershell -NoProfile -Command get-NetIPInterface` was more relevant though. Now I'm trying to find how I could search if a particular ifIndex exists in the output table.

Comment: `findstr` can help you.